# TableView won't allow me to press up and transfer view. Obj-C, Cocoa Touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

So I have an app that contains a tableView. When you press on a row, it should go to a new view controller and transfer the results. But it only sort-of works. If you press on a row, it will stay selected (Highlighted blue), but then if you select a different row, it will release the press on the first row and then move to the corresponding view. Sorry if this is a little confusing. Here is a short video of the error --> http://vid.ly/1e8u0h

It would seem as though the problem is that when I tap on a row, it never sends the "tap up" action, therefore doesn't continue with this method :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

    NSArray *items = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
    BNRItem *selectedItem = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [detailViewController setItem:selectedItem];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` :) Easy fix. Happy Coding.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sometimes it just takes that extra pair of eyes.

Comment: @gamma won by a nose, dvorak ftw :p +1 for the same answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You schould use `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath.`